# How to assign non null values in one group to all rows in the group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 23    |
|  1 | NA    |
|  1 | NA    |
|  1 | NA    |
|  2 | 24    |
|  2 | NA    |
|  2 | NA    |
+----+-------+
```

For each ID value in a group, I either have one value or NA. I wanted to apply this non NA value to the NA values in that specific group as below.

Desired Output :

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 23    |
|  1 | 23    |
|  1 | 23    |
|  1 | 23    |
|  2 | 24    |
|  2 | 24    |
|  2 | 24    |
+----+-------+
```

How can we achieve this in pandas?

Comment: `df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Value']).fffill()`

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Just one change. df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Value']).ffill()

Answer (score 2):

Check with

```
df.Value.fillna(df.groupby('ID').Value.transform('first'), inplace=True)
```

Comment: Heyy benyo, Good seeing you here. Thanks for your cumsum solution, it really did the trick. ~ And wishing you Happy Coding as well.

Comment: @High-Octane happy coding ~

Answer (score 1):

say your dataframe variable is `df`

**Then,**

```
df.value.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Should do the trick.

Documentation for your reference :

[Forward Fill Documentation Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

Comment: thanks. RichieV's answer worked for me